# Flink (1.2) window is producing more than 1 ouput per window

Tags: streaming, apache-kafka, apache-flink, windowing

**The question:** the problem is that this program is writing to Kafka more than once every window (is creating 2-3 or more lines per window, meanwhile it is supposed to create 1 line per window as with the `reduce` function it lets only one element). I have the same code written in Spark and it works perfectly. I have been trying to find info about this issue and I haven't found anything :(. Also I have been trying changing some functions' parallelism and some more things and nothing worked, and I can not realise where can be the problem.

I am testing Flink latency. Here you have the environment of my problem:

**Cluster**: I am using Flink 1.2.0 and OpenJDK 8. I have 3 computers: 1 JobManager, 2 TaskManagers (4 cores, 2GB RAM, 4 task slots each TaskManager).

**Input data:** lines produced by one java producer to the Kafka 24 partitions' topic with two elements: incremental value and creation timestamp:

- 1 1497790546981
- 2 1497790546982
- 3 1497790546983
- 4 1497790546984
- ............................

**My Java Class:**

- It reads from  a Kafka topic with 24 partitions (Kafka is in the same machine than the JobManager).
- The `filter` functions are useless together with the `union` as I use them just for checking their latency.
- Basically, it adds a "1" to each line,then there is a `tumbling window` every 2 seconds, and the `reduce` function sum all this 1's and all the timestamps, this last timestamp is later divided in the `map` function between the sum of 1's which gives me the average, and finally in the last `map` function it adds a timestamp of the current moment to each reduced line and the difference between this timestamp and the average timestamp.
- This line is written to Kafka (to a 2 partitions' topic).

  ```
      //FLINK CONFIGURATION
      final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment
              .getExecutionEnvironment();

      env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime);


      //KAFKA CONSUMER CONFIGURATION
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.0.155:9092");
      FlinkKafkaConsumer010<String> myConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<>(args[0], new SimpleStringSchema(), properties);


      //KAFKA PRODUCER
      Properties producerConfig = new Properties();
      producerConfig.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.0.155:9092");
      producerConfig.setProperty("acks", "0");
      producerConfig.setProperty("linger.ms", "0");


      //MAIN PROGRAM
      //Read from Kafka
      DataStream<String> line = env.addSource(myConsumer);

      //Add 1 to each line
      DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> line_Num = line.map(new NumberAdder());

      //Filted Odd numbers
      DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> line_Num_Odd = line_Num.filter(new FilterOdd());

      //Filter Even numbers
      DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> line_Num_Even = line_Num.filter(new FilterEven());

      //Join Even and Odd
      DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> line_Num_U = line_Num_Odd.union(line_Num_Even);

      //Tumbling windows every 2 seconds
      AllWindowedStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>, TimeWindow> windowedLine_Num_U = line_Num_U
              .windowAll(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(2)));

      //Reduce to one line with the sum
      DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> wL_Num_U_Reduced = windowedLine_Num_U.reduce(new Reducer());

      //Calculate the average of the elements summed
      DataStream<String> wL_Average = wL_Num_U_Reduced.map(new AverageCalculator());

      //Add timestamp and calculate the difference with the average
      DataStream<String> averageTS = wL_Average.map(new TimestampAdder());


      //Send the result to Kafka
      FlinkKafkaProducer010Configuration<String> myProducerConfig = (FlinkKafkaProducer010Configuration<String>) FlinkKafkaProducer010
              .writeToKafkaWithTimestamps(averageTS, "testRes", new SimpleStringSchema(), producerConfig);

      myProducerConfig.setWriteTimestampToKafka(true);

      env.execute("TimestampLongKafka");
  }


  //Functions used in the program implementation:

  public static class FilterOdd implements FilterFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      public boolean filter(Tuple2<String, Integer> line) throws Exception {
          Boolean isOdd = (Long.valueOf(line._1.split(" ")[0]) % 2) != 0;
          return isOdd;
      }
  };


  public static class FilterEven implements FilterFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      public boolean filter(Tuple2<String, Integer> line) throws Exception {
          Boolean isEven = (Long.valueOf(line._1.split(" ")[0]) % 2) == 0;
          return isEven;
      }
  };


  public static class NumberAdder implements MapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      public Tuple2<String, Integer> map(String line) {
          Tuple2<String, Integer> newLine = new Tuple2<String, Integer>(line, 1);
          return newLine;
      }
  };


  public static class Reducer implements ReduceFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      public Tuple2<String, Integer> reduce(Tuple2<String, Integer> line1, Tuple2<String, Integer> line2) throws Exception {
          Long sum = Long.valueOf(line1._1.split(" ")[0]) + Long.valueOf(line2._1.split(" ")[0]);
          Long sumTS = Long.valueOf(line1._1.split(" ")[1]) + Long.valueOf(line2._1.split(" ")[1]);
          Tuple2<String, Integer> newLine = new Tuple2<String, Integer>(String.valueOf(sum) + " " + String.valueOf(sumTS), 
                  line1._2 + line2._2);
          return newLine;
      }
  };


  public static class AverageCalculator implements MapFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, String> {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      public String map(Tuple2<String, Integer> line) throws Exception {
          Long average = Long.valueOf(line._1.split(" ")[1]) / line._2;
          String result = String.valueOf(line._2) + " " + String.valueOf(average);
          return result;
      }
  };


  public static final class TimestampAdder implements MapFunction<String, String> {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      public String map(String line) throws Exception {
          Long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
          String totalTime = String.valueOf(currentTime - Long.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]));
          String newLine = line.concat(" " + String.valueOf(currentTime) + " " + totalTime);

          return newLine;
      }
  };
  ```

**Some output data:** this output has been written to the 2 partitions' topic, and with a producing rate of less than 1000 records/second (**in this case it is creating 3 output lines per window):

- *1969 149779124**0910** 1497791241999 1089 1497791242001 1091*
- *1973 149779124**0971** 1497791241999 1028 1497791242002 1031*
- *1970 149779124**0937** 1497791242094 1157 1497791242198 1261*
- 1917 149779124**2912** 1497791243999 1087 1497791244051 1139
- 1905 149779124**2971** 1497791243999 1028 1497791244051 1080
- 1916 149779124**2939** 1497791244096 1157 1497791244199 1260
- *1994 149779124**4915** 1497791245999 1084 1497791246002 1087*
- *1993 149779124**4966** 1497791245999 1033 1497791246004 1038*
- *1990 149779124**4939** 1497791246097 1158 1497791246201 1262*

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but a couple of things seem a bit odd: Why set the time characteristic to event time, then never setup a timestamp extractor and watermark generator, and then use processing time windows? And why have an infrastructure capable of parallel processing, and then use windowAll, which gathers all records into one task?

Comment: TimeCharacteristic: I use a consumer later for copying the results to a file and I use record.timestamp() so I need to setWriteTimestampToKafka(true) in my program. windowAll: I haven't done it yet, I have though about adding a key after both filters so the window can be done with parallelism=2

Comment: I forgot, I have changed EventTime to ProcessingTime! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why, but I can fix the problem **stopping the Flink cluster and starting it again**. After some job executions it starts to produce more outputs, at leats x3, and probably the problem can keep growing. I will open an issue on Jira and update this as soon as possible.